# Publish contacts to PactBroker using pactNet

Tags: pact-net

I have a pact file generated by using pactNet Pact V3 , now how do I post the pact file to pact-broker. I have done a lot of reading using Curl, ruby and java (with Gradle) for this purpose but did not see anything equivalent for C#. Is there anyone achieve this before and any guidance is appreciated.

I am expecting pactNet V3 exposes a method to publish contracts to pactBroker . I currently have docker pactBroker up and running on my local host

Answer (score 1):

PackNet doesn't expose a method to publish the contract. You can use the CLI tooling to do that. For example, you can use the [dockerized version of the tooling](https://hub.docker.com/r/pactfoundation/pact-cli) to publish the contract generated by your test.

Comment: Looks like Pact-broker Client CLI can be used, not specifically dockerized version. See: https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/client_cli